Equal-time Kadanoff-Baym equation for scalar field propagators
My problem is that in most of the literature on non-equilibrium field theory, the Hamiltonian formalism is used. The left and right KBE for a free theory with $H = \omega_0 c^\dagger c$ (for simplicity) are then given by
\begin{gather}
\left(i\partial_{t_1} - H\right)G(t_1,t_2) = \delta_{t_1,t_2}\\
G(t_1,t_2)\left(-i\partial_{t_2} - H\right) = \delta_{t_1,t_2}
\end{gather}
where in the second line the derivative acts to the left and the propagator is of the form
$G(1,2) = -i \langle T_C c(1) c^\dagger (2) \rangle$. In this case it is easy to see that by subtraction of the two KBEs and setting $t_1 = t_2$
\begin{equation}
 \partial_t G(t,t) = [H,G(t,t)] = 0
\end{equation}
as it should be, since $G$ should only depend on the time difference of it's arguments not on the mean time $T = \frac{t_1 + t_2}{2}$.
Now to my question:
Given the free scalar 1D field theory $L = \frac{1}{2}(\partial_t\phi(t))^2 - \frac{1}{2}\omega_0^2 \phi^2(t)$, the left and right KBE are again straight forward. With $G_0^{-1} = -\partial_t^2 - \omega_0^2$ and $G(1,2) = -i \langle T_C \phi(1) \phi (2) \rangle$,
\begin{gather}
\left(-\partial_{t_1}^2 - \omega_0^2\right)G(t_1,t_2) = \delta_{t_1,t_2}\\
G(t_1,t_2)\left(-\partial_{t_2}^2 - \omega_0^2\right) = \delta_{t_1,t_2}
\end{gather}
However, it seems impossible to me to obtain an evolution equation for the diagonal component of the propagator. Using Wigner coordinates $T = \frac{t_1 + t_2}{2}$ and $\tau = t_1 - t_2$, both the sum and difference of the two KBEs contain both $T$ and $\tau$ derivatives due to the KBEs containing only second time derivatives. In particular, the sum of the left and right KBE in this case reads
\begin{equation}
\left( - \partial_{t_1}^2 - \partial_{t_2}^2 - 2\omega_0^2\right) G(t_1,t_2)\vert_{t_1 = t_2} = \left( - \frac{1}{2}\partial_{T}^2 - 2\partial_{\tau}^2 - 2\omega_0^2\right) G(T,\tau)\vert_{T=t_1,\tau=0} = 2\delta_{t_1,t_2} .
\end{equation}
and the difference reads
\begin{equation}
\left( - \partial_{t_1}^2 + \partial_{t_2}^2 \right) G(t_1,t_2)\vert_{t_1 = t_2} =  - 2\partial_{T}\partial_{\tau} G(T,\tau)\vert_{T=t_1,\tau=0} = 0 .
\end{equation}
Notice that in the equations above there is a symmetry between exchanging $T$ and $\tau$.
Of course, you could argue that we know that in the sum-equation the $2\omega_0^2$ part comes from the $2\partial_\tau^2$ derivative and therefore the $\partial_T^2$ is zero. However, in the case where I don't consider a free theory, and I am not in equilibrium, I know neither the evolution with respect to $\tau$ nor $T$. To be able to make a time-step along the diagonal, i.e. $T$ to $T+\delta t$ one needs to know the evolution equation for $T$ independently.
How is this achieved?

Feynman propagator rolls both positive and negative frequencies into one object.  You should disentangle the two parts before doing anything Hamiltonian.
Factorize $-\partial_t^2 - \omega_0^2 = (i\partial_t - \omega_0)(i\partial_t + \omega_0)$.  The propagator $G$ can now be written as the sum of two terms: $G = G_+ + G_-$, where $\mp2\omega_0 (i\partial_t \pm \omega_0) G_\pm = \delta$.  Now whatever you are trying should go through separately for $G_+$ and $G_-$.
edit
As far as I know, the only way to avoid Hamiltonian altogether is to do path integral quantization with a Lagrangian action.  I don't know if this is what you have in mind when you say "Lagrangian formalism".   But if you don't do path integral, then the classical Lagrangian is only a way to define the Hamiltonian system to be canonically quantized.
Suppose you have manifest time translational symmetry in action $S[\phi]$.  Consider the partition function with source $J(t)$:
$$
Z[J] = \int \mathcal{D}\phi \, \exp\left(iS[\phi] + i\int dt J(t) \phi(t) \right) = \int \mathcal{D}\phi \, \exp\left(iS[\phi] + i\int dt J(t+\Delta t) \phi(t) \right).
$$
The second equality is merely a field redefinition of $\phi$.  Take functional derivatives and you get $G(t_1, t_2) = G(t_1 + \Delta t, t_2 + \Delta t)$.

I am not trying to use the Hamiltonian formalism.

But you are trying to replicate a result that is usually derived within the Hamiltonian approach.  In any case, I do believe the mixing of $\pm \omega_0$ in Feynman propagator is the source of your problem.

Yes you are right in your assesment. Hawever, the Hamiltonian and Lagrangian formalisms are equivalent and it should be possible to obtain what I want in the Lagrangian formalism I think.
